# Logo do Stack Overflow usado como ícone em site de terceiros

Tags: debate, status-pronto

Estava dando uma olhada **[num certo site](http://kuiper.com.br/sobre-o-kuiper)** e para minha surpresa, vi esse ícone:

[image: screenshot]

Familiar, não? (rolando a tela mais ou menos 50% da página).

Qual o procedimento num caso desses? O *staff* resolve isso?

> EDIT: Já substituiram o ícone. Problema resolvido.

Comment: Affe! É cada um...

Comment: Hahahaha! Certamente é uso ilícito do logo. Você pode postar isso no metão, avisar pelo [formulário de contato](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) ou mandar um email para team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: @bfavaretto ja mandei por email tb :)

Comment: Parece que trocaram...

Comment: Será que viram isto aqui, ou pediram pra eles tirarem? :)

Comment: Tirei a tag do título e sinalizei pra botarem a de verdade.

Comment: Uau, atualizaram para a logo do Buffer: https://bufferapp.com/

Comment: Uau, vcs são viciados em logos. =P

Comment: Bom, acessei e não vi o logo do Buffer. Será que estão acompanhando a discussão? :)

Comment: tá em branco agora, rsrs

Comment: Por um determinando momento achei que estivessem falando do "novo" [GUJ](http://www.guj.com.br/).

Answer (score 4):

Exitem diversos conjuntos de ícones e fontes (pagos e grátis) que possuem uma variedade de logotipos conhecidos entre os outros pictogramas. Estes logos tem como objetivo ajudar o desenvolvedor caso ele precise fazer referência à alguma empresa.

Por exemplo:

```
Nos siga no Twitter ! (inserem o logo aqui)
```

ou:

```
Dúvidas? Utilize a comunidade StackOverflow.com! (logotipo aqui)
```

O que ocorre, ao meu ver, é que alguns desses logos não são vastamente conhecidos, principalmente pelo designer que propõe o layout de uma página. O designer vê o ícone, não conhece nenhuma empresa que usa ele, acha ele adequado, e pronto, joga na arte.

Isso ocorre muito, eu mesmo quando comecei a trabalhar com web design já cometi essas gafes. Acho que este caso foi mais ignorância do que maldade de fato.

É claro que quando um logo está sendo utilizado indevidamente (como nesse caso) a comunidade **deve sim** entrar em contato com a empresa e tomar as atitudes cabíveis para a remoção do mesmo. Mas só devemos nos lembrar que nem sempre o site ou empresa utilizou o logo de maldade, as vezes foi ignorância e apenas um aviso amigável resolve toda a situação.

Answer (score 2):

Bom, tem de se ver então. O Fontawsome fornece esse mesmo ícone como parte do seu set.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/stack-overflow/

Acredito que o propósito, nesse caso, é fornecer algo relacionado ao SO, assim como existem logos do G. Plus, Facebook, Twitter, Github e afins.